# Is it possible to create Try Catch block which will run every single function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, reporting-services, playwright

So, my question is generally about some debugging and troubleshooting for people who don't really understand programming at all.
Is it possible to create a method like:

```
public foo(method){
try(){
method();
}
catch(error){
console.log(method().name + 'caused an error'); 
throw Error;
}
```

is it generally okay to do something like that, yes, I know that errors are shown very good even without something similar but if, for example I'm doing testing for a client who wants to know about everything and see what's exactly goes wrong. I'd like to let him know about problems as much as I can, I already have allure reporter on my project but it is not enough

Comment: Yes, but your syntax is off and you shouldn't `throw` inside your `catch`. That defeats the entire purpose unless you're bubbling up the error to another `try/catch`

Comment: @Andrew re-throwing an exception from inside a `catch` block is extremely common practice in Java code. It's a way of doing exactly what's done here, logging a particular error at a more-specific layer of code.

Comment: OP it should be `method.name` not `method().name`

Comment: @Pointy I don't doubt that one bit, but I don't think it's common to do so in JavaScript. If the error is bubbled up and caught elsewhere, then yea totally that's fine. But intentionally crashing runtime? I find that questionable and have never seen that before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is. But there are so many good ways to use logger to use allure report with step description for every single method that you run.

So people will see every action which is called in human-readable form.
They will have a stack trace with screenshot and video, it can't get better than that.

To use allure in playwright.config file use

```
reporter: [
    ["allure-playwright"],
    ["list"]
],
```

also, list

```
"allure-commandline": "^2.13.0",
"allure-playwright": "^2.0.0-beta.14",
```

in package.json

You can cal every method like this

```
await test.step('Exatc action in method described in human readable language e.g. Click Send Button', async () => {
    // ...your method
  });
```

Also, there is a test error built-in playwright, so you do not need to build your own. See section:

```
testStep.error
type: <TestError>
```

on:
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-teststep#test-step-error

For opening allure use:

```
"open-allure": "allure generate ./target/allure-results -c ./allure-report && allure open",
```

And one more thing. Playwright has the best debug mode on market, it shows your code and every action in browser see: https://playwright.dev/docs/inspector